# anyone who has not done their homework

Tags: negation, any

a. Anyone who has not done their homework can't watch television tonight.

b. Anyone who has not done their homework will not be allowed to watch television tonight.

c. Anyone who has not done their homework is not allowed to watch television tonight.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct and meaningful?

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, they're all correct.

As a native speaker of English, I'd say that all of these sentences are correct and meaningful. There is some slight differences in meaning, largely due to the differences in tense, however.

I would say that B would mean that anyone who has not done their homework by tonight will not be allowed to watch television, while C would mean that anyone who has not already done their homework (as this sentence is said) will not be allowed to watch television tonight. Sentence A is somewhat more ambiguous about timing, but it's saying that watching television will not be possible without the completion of homework; it's a somewhat stronger way of saying "will not be allowed".